# aligning inset plots in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

How do I align an inset plot in multiplot so that the right and top frames of both plots coincide so that I get something like in this plot:
[image]

I tried to read the documentation on coordinates but I do not understand that at all and thus I cannot properly set origin and size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify the size of the inset relative to the main figure using `set size`, and then move its bottom left corner using `set origin` so that the top right corner is at (1,1). For example,

```
set multiplot

plot exp(-x)            # plot main figure

set size 0.6, 0.5       # set size of inset
set origin 0.4, 0.5     # move bottom left corner of inset
plot cos(x)             # plot inset

unset multiplot
```

gives

[image]

Of course you will have to adjust tick labels and legends to avoid overlaps in the composite figure.